# PHP 7.4 and Ubuntu 18 - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so'

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl

I'm using [the ondrej ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) for PHP and am running Ubuntu 18. Running `php -v` gives me the following output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/curl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/curl.so: symbol curl_mime_addpart version CURL_OPENSSL_4 not defined in file libcurl.so.4 with link time reference), /usr/lib/php/20190902/curl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/curl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2020 11:21:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Basically, I can't run any `composer` commands because a lot of libraries depend on curl, and apparently it isn't being found. I've done the following:

1. Tried to update everything (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl`). This doesn't fix the issue.
2. Restarted apache despite this being the cli version.
3. Double checked where it's trying to find the library. What's weird is that `/usr/lib/php/20190902/curl.so` is a valid path and the file is definitely there.

Running `php --ini` also shows that the curl extension is loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
...more ini files...
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
...more ini files...
```

I'm unsure how to fix this as the file it supposedly can not find is exactly where it says it looked, and everything is up to date.

Comment: Didnt you compile the cURL with the PHP executables?

Comment: I believe so. I'm just using that ondrej ppa and did `sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl`. I never did any manual compiling.

Comment: If you remove the extension=curl.... from the php.ini and do phpinfo(); do u see curl in the output?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone with this issue, the answer is [here](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1322).

Basically, the libcurl that was installed on my Ubuntu machine clashed with the official one that Ubuntu has? Weirdly it was only affecting php7.3 and 7.4 and not 7.2. Anyways, I renamed the libcurl module like so:

`mv /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0.backup`

And by running `php -m`, I could verify that the cURL module was now enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I found that if I did:
`apt search | more`
(the pipe is for long lists)
that I could find the php package name that I needed.

For example:
`apt search curl`
told me that the name of the package for my php version is 'php7.2-curl'

So, all I had to do was `sudo apt install php7.2 curl`.
I repeated this (some names require a little googling, and/or some apt search creativity.

Comment: You should install `php-curl` to get the default. use the specific version only if you need that older version. Also it looks like you're missing a dash in your last example (`php7.2-curl`, right?)

Answer (score 3):

**I solved it by doing this:**

1. Uninstall curl:

```
apt remove php7.4-curl
```

2. New install:

```
apt install php7.4-curl
```

I have now all right.

Answer (score 2):

I am using php8.2, so I did this :

```bash
sudo apt-get install php8.2-curl
```

Then I checked the php modules by using this command :

```bash
php -m
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to run `composer update` things were failing because the deps where from php -v 7 while I was using 8.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

worked for me